# Drag and Drop(event) not trigger ajax POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have three pages: test.php, script.js, and main.php.

Main.php is using html5 drag and drop along with a simple ajax script from script.js, in an effort to post to- and activate test.php. (side note, i would like main.php to pass the `<img id="s1" />` as a POST variable. After several hours of research and a hundred or so tests and revisions I am unable to figure out why I cannot get ondrop to trigger the post. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

test.php (contains a simple php script that when loaded inserts a generic record into my DB)

script.js

```
function drop(id, event) {
   $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id,
            event: event
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log('great success');
            return true
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

and main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
<header class="main-header" role="banner"><center>
  <img src="lampettalogo.jpg" height="90" width="400"alt="Banner Image"/></center>
</header>
<style>

#1 {width:auto;height:auto;padding:1px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
#2 {width:auto;height:auto;padding:1px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
#3 {width:auto;height:auto;padding:1px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
#4 {width:auto;height:auto;padding:1px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;overflow: auto;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<?php 
include "database_connection.php";
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
else
{
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM ss where currentZone = 1";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<img id='{$row["sID"]}' src='{$row["photoLink"]}.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' width='75' height='75'>"  ;
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
 mysqli_close($link);
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
</div>
<div id="2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<?php
include "database_connection.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM ss where currentZone = 2";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {        
        echo "<img id='{$row["sID"]}' src='{$row["photoLink"]}.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' ondrop='drop(event)' width='75' height='75'>"  ;
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
</div>
<div id="3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<?php
include "database_connection.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM ss where currentZone = 3";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {        
        echo "<img id='{$row["sID"]}' src='{$row["photoLink"]}.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' width='75' height='75'>"  ;
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
</div>
<div id="4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<?php
include "database_connection.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM ss where currentZone = 4";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {        
        echo "<img id='{$row["sID"]}' src='{$row["photoLink"]}.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' width='75' height='75'>"  ;
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
</div>
<div id="4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<?php
include "database_connection.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM ss where currentZone = 0";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {        
        echo "<img id='{$row["sID"]}' src='{$row["photoLink"]}.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' width='75' height='75'>"  ;
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: none. it just doesnt do anything.

Comment: You don't have allowDrop() function

Comment: I wasn't aware allow drop was needed. does that go on the droppable item, or the containing being dropped in?

Comment: You need to add `function allowDrop(e) { e.preventDefault(); }` in your `script.js`. Are you also looking to `POST` the file to `test.php`?

Comment: On the div of the originbox and dropbox. You are using the function but you did not initialize it.

Comment: Check this for guidelines. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrop.asp

Comment: yes I am looking to post to the test.php. could you show your thoughts as an answer? I seem to be missing some braincells tonight

Comment: Is the function not being called?

Comment: it is not, however, if I revert back to a previous script.js I can get it to work as far as drag and drop, but it does not call the function because it doesn't excist anymore. Is the way my function is written as posted above incorrect somehow?
`function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}`

Comment: I just realized with my script as it was above, i could no longer drag/drop. i wasnt away that was the case upon posting.

Comment: Can you update the question with the rest of your javascript code like the allowdrop function. Perhaps a jsfiddle

Comment: The code I posted in the question is the entire file, copy and pasted. I know I am missing something, but it seems to difficult to get help here as a beginner. I just reverted back to the code above, in the previous comment to get drag and drop back to working. I wasn't aware i broke drag and drop with the js file in the question. I am really lost. There is nothing else currently in the script.js besides what is in the comment above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `drop(id, e)` method, you can consider the following, in addition to your `allowDrop` method. Use the `FileReader` class to read your file.

```
function drop(id, e) {
  if (e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files.length != 0) {
    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0], // Only the first file.
      reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onload = function (event) {
      console.log(file.name);
      $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          id: id,
          fileName: file.name, // Your file name.
          file: event.target.result // Your file.
        },
        success: function () {
          console.log('great success');
          return true
        }
      });
    };
  }
}
```

And in your HTML, you need to pass a value in `id` as well. For example, you can do the following to print out your `$row["sID"]` into the method parameter.

```
<div id="1" ondrop="drop('<?php echo $row["sID"]; ?>', event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```

On your PHP script, you need to be able to receive the `POST`ed file. An example is shown below.

```
$data = $_POST['file'];
$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$serverFile = $fileName . "-" . time(); // Appends timestamp so that files of the same name wouldn't be overwritten.
$fp = fopen('/uploads/' . $serverFile, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
$returnData = array( "serverFile" => $serverFile );
echo json_encode($returnData);
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dpgBtdWEvc0TibdB9daB?p=preview) for an example. Drop a file into the div, and watch the console log.

---

**Edit**

Understood that you want to drag and drop elements instead.

Below is the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXzRo0?p=preview).

Comment: if I go with your method for script.js, I can no longer drag/drop. Is there something else I should be adding in? It does work if i do drop(ev) instead of drop(id, event)

edit* by adding `function allowDrop(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); } function drag(ev) { ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id); }` do the JS i can drag, but cannot drop.

Comment: Because your parameters must match the method signature. You asked (on a side note) that you would like to pass the `id` as well, so I've given the answer as well. However, if you'd like to not pass the `id`, then just remove the `id` parameter from the method signature.

Comment: Yep, consider printing out `$row["sID"]` as your parameter value, say `ondrop="drop('<?php echo $row["sID"]; ?>', event)"`.

Comment: would you be willing to provide an example of what you would do with my code? I do not seem to be grasping the concept. I am pretty new to JS and ajax. I guess my question would be, if I use your script.js, why does my drag and drop stop working as. My working JS code is `function allowDrop(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); } function drag(ev) { ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id); } function drop(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"); ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); } `

I am really sorry for being slow, just trying to figure this out.

Comment: No worries! In my script.js, I had the `id` parameter (i.e. `drop(id, e)` (as you've asked in your question). But I believe in your existing HTML, you're still passing just one parameter (without the `id`, i.e. `drop(e)`). So `drop(id, e)` would read `id = e` and `e = null` (with the file being passed as the first parameter, which isn't what we want). The correction would be to pass your `id="s1"` as a parameter value in your div, **or** you remove `id` as a parameter in my script.js.

Comment: How would I go about passing it as a parameter? Because that is what I'm hoping. Keep in mind I still don't have the drag and drop calling the test.php. More important than the parameters being passed is that I call the PHP file sucessfully, which isn't happening now. can you see a reason why using my main.php and your script.js that drag and drop is not calling test.php?

Comment: See the `index.html` file of this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/clsDdHch3804O6QNuWtd?p=preview) for a better explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. the issue is resolved.